# Mysql запрос на вывод 3 строк в одну

Tags: php, mysql

возможен ли такой запрос:
есть таблица в которой есть 2 колонки
name и text
Мне нужно вытащить в одном запросе и в одной строке 3 данных
То есть есть простой запрос

```
SELECT text FROM table WHERE name IN ("1", "2", "3");
```

Но он выводит 3 строки а мне нужно 1 строку вывести в которой будет text первого второго и третьего name
чтобы потом не использовать while или foreach
возможно ли такое?

Comment: Используйте GROUP_CONCAT https://expange.ru/e/GROUP_CONCAT_(MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо ответ не нужен
вот решение, вдруг кому надо

```
SELECT text AS text1, (SELECT text AS text2 FROM languages_template WHERE name = '2') AS text2, 
(SELECT text AS text3 FROM languages_template WHERE name = '3') AS text3 FROM languages_template WHERE name = '1';
```

Comment: У вас стрёмное решение. А если строк будет 10? Вы будете 10 подзапросов писать? А если 100?

Comment: мне необходимо было именно 3 значения вывести ( позже не потребуется больше так же ) 
если строк будет много то можно и циклом воспользоваться
тут просто другая ситуация, и из за этого данный запрос подходит мне )

Comment: Это туфта, а не решение.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUBSTRING(
(
    SELECT text AS 'data()'
        FROM table 
        where name in ("1", "2", "3")
        FOR XML PATH('')

), 2 , 9999) As name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN name=1 THEN text END) text1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name=2 THEN text END) text2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name=3 THEN text END) text3
FROM languages_template 
WHERE name IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Пример с использованием GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text) AS texts FROM table WHERE name IN ("1", "2", "3");
```